# How to create a session to display a users Login name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I am a bit of a ASP.NET/VB noobie so sorry in advance for any stupid questions.

I am currently creating a ASP.NET application using VB. The application I have had is connected to a local Database and I am able redirect a user to a "Users" page once they have input their login credentials correctly.

What I want to happen is that once they login and are redirected to the "Users" page, there will be a message saying "Welcome" followed by their login name.

I have been able to successfully do this in C# but need to be able to do so in VB as well.

The code that worked in C# is as follows;

```
**Session["New"] = TextBoxUserName.Text;
                Response.Write("Password is correct");
                Response.Redirect("Users.aspx");**
```

I've tried putting this code straight into my VB project but have received the following error;

**"Property access must assign to the property or use its value"**

I've done some research into this error and can't seem to find any solution to the problem.

Is my syntax incorrect or are sessions used completely different in VB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen your VB Code but it should be:

```
Session("New") = TextBoxUserName.Text
''Response.Write("Password is correct"); - No point in having this line as the redirect overrides it quickly.
Response.Redirect("Users.aspx")
```

Note the use of round brackets rather than square brackets for VB, also note the lackof semi colons. VB.NET and C# are completely different syntax wise.

Comment: Brilliant, that has worked perfectly! I have removed the Response.Write line as suggested. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: No problem, mark the question if everything's okay.